# VkApi - Vk.Net Проблема со списком групп пользователя

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я пытаюсь достать список всех групп которые есть у моего пользователя:

Код:

```
GroupsGetParams gp = new GroupsGetParams();
gp.UserId = VkApi.UserId;

var varkets = VkApi.Groups.Get(gp);
```

---

Выдает ошибку:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'VkNet.Exception.UserAuthorizationFailException' occurred in VkNet.dll
>
> Additional information: User authorization failed: no access_token
>   passed.

Пользователь, конечно же, залогинен со всеми правами (Settings settingsScope = Settings.All;) и должен иметь доступ к списку групп.

В чем дело? Список друзей таким же способом достается без проблем.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Прошу прощения за оффтоп, а двухфакторная аутентификация у Вас работает, при использовании этой библиотеки?

Comment: а как вам разрешило дать доступ к Settings.All? У меня после такого тупо не идет авторизация.

Comment: @ep1demic  двухфакторная авторизация работает, но это отдельный метод у меня. Если галочка стоит -- логинюсь через нее. Если не стоит - простая авторизация.На вопрос про сеттингс.Алл - не знаю, проблем с этим не возникало.

Comment: @Kiya т. е. пользователь сам  указывает, нужна ли ему двухэтапная аутентификация?

Answer (score 1):

> Список друзей таким же способом достается без проблем.

Список друзей достаётся без проблем потому что друзья у пользователя, которого вы парсите открыты и видны всем.

> Я пытаюсь достать список всех групп

А вот для просмотра списка групп вероятно надо быть другом или там ещё более приватные настройки просмотра.

Посмотрите на странице https://vk.com/dev/friends.get написано:
Этот метод можно вызвать без ключа доступа.
А на странице про группы: Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя
И варианта без ключа нет.

Где взять ключ? Почитайте тут https://vk.com/dev/access_token Вкратце: надо авторизовать юзера в приложении а вместе с ответом на callback_url придёт специальный токен по которому потом и получите ключ.

Итоговый запрос будет выглядеть так (извините я на php):

```
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?user_id=3654645645&count=1000&access_token=dfsghdsghfghfghfghf89h");
```

access_token только нужный подставите

Comment: судя по коду gp.UserId = VkApi.UserId; - человек и пытается достать список груп СВОЕГО пользователя. Ведь VkApi.UserId и есть айдишник залогиненого пользователя ;)

Comment: Даже если он пытается достать своего, в вопросе нет конкретного указания на то что он передаёт свой токен

Comment: Если токен неверный, будет ошибка "AccessTokenInvalidException". И невозможно было бы даже друзей собрать. Или я ошибаюсь? :) И, кстате говоря, токен в даной библиотеке, на сколько мне известно, является ридонли. И он сам подхватывается в момент логина пользователя в вк.